# How to convert Datetime value to date time

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5.3, php-carbon

I have a datetime value  `20170109221930` given by my client.I can't understand how to convert this value to datetime. Also I can't understand which format (`20170109221930`)  my client give me?

Comment: it is in the format YMDHMS format

Comment: it means 2017/01/09 22:19:30

Comment: Might be worth in future _asking your client_

Answer (score 2):

use createFromFormat to create datetime from a string. then you can use format to format it.

```
$string = '20170109221930';
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', $string));
```

output:

```
ei@localhost:~$ php test.php
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2017-01-09 22:19:30"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(14) "Asia/Chongqing"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Laravel you can use [Carbon's](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) `parse()` or `createFromFormat()` methods:

```
$dateObject = Carbon::parse('20170109221930');
```

After that you'll be able to use tens Carbon methods to convert this timestamp to whatever format you want:

```
$dateObject->format(h:i:s);
$dateObject->toDateTimeString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon method in Laravel like this:

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($your_time)->format('d.m.Y') }}
```

in your view file.

You can find more info

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/use-carbon-at-blade-template?page=1